# How to read Google Sheets on web page using Javascript? I was using Tabletop but it stopped working last week

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Our nonprofit organization has a Google Sheets file with many tabs (sheets). We need to display selected pieces of data from two of the sheets on two different web pages in our WordPress website.

Starting a couple years ago, we set up the Google Sheets to publish to the web (and selected the two sheets that need to be published). Since that time we have been using tabletop.js and some simple Javascript to retrieve and display the data.

Here's an example of the code on one of the pages. For this post I munged the URL since this spreadsheet includes lots of names and email addresses that shouldn't be made public.

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabletop.js/1.5.1/tabletop.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    // This is the address of the Google Sheet containing the IG database
    var publicSpreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13XSjvsIgviUqd2zxxxxxxxxxsRO3OIf78Hyw/edit?usp=sharing';

    function init() {
        Tabletop.init( { key: publicSpreadsheetUrl,callback: showInfo,simpleSheet: false } )
    }

    function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
        var sheet = data.EnrolledAll.elements;
        console.log(sheet);
        var targetIG = document.getElementById('IGCode').innerHTML;
        var igRoster="";

        // Walk IG DB, building selected roster 
        for (i = 0; i < sheet.length; i++) {
            if (sheet[i].ig==targetIG) {
                igRoster=igRoster + "<li>" + sheet[i].name;
                if (sheet[i].class!="")
                    igRoster=igRoster + " (" + sheet[i].class + ")";
                igRoster=igRoster + "</li>";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('IGRoster').innerHTML=igRoster;
    }
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
</script>
```

This worked as desired for a couple years, but last week (approx. 8/13/2021) this stopped working. The Tabletop.init is now getting a 404 when trying to retrieve the Google Sheets data. The browser console log shows a 404 when trying to access a URL like this (apparently transformed by tabletop and/or Google):

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/13XSjvsIgviUqd2zYUxxxxxxxx_3mTsRO3OIf78Hyw/public/basic?alt=json
```

I have heard that Google has made some security changes recently, and suspect that this might be the root cause.

Do I need to use Google Sheets API, or is there a simpler replacement for Tabletop? Note that I need data from two different sheets, but each web page only needs to read data from one of the sheets.

Comment: Your question is quite opinion based. You can use [Sheets API Javascript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js?hl=en) to read your sheets data or you can use other methods to read your sheets such as Papa Parse w/c was suggested in [Tabletop github](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop).

Answer (score 0):

Tabletop.js access to Google Sheets is now officially disabled by the Google turndown of the Sheets API v3.
https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop/issues/192#issuecomment-897435587

So I will be applying the Google Sheets API to read data from Google Sheets. Their migration guide is here:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api

UPDATE: I created an API Key for the Google Sheets API, and used that along with Papa Parse to read the data from the Google Sheet.  I finally realized that the API Key doesn't have to be part of the same Apps Script project that is attached to the Google Sheet. They can be totally separate unrelated projects, you just need an API Key to be able to read the sheet from our web page javascript.